# neovim: [coc.nvim]: UnhandledRejection: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed

Tags: ubuntu, neovim, coc.nvim

my neovim have an error when i try to open a python file

throws me:

```
[coc.nvim]: UnhandledRejection: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed                                
Error: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed                                                         
    at Object.dispose (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:51:4565)                                       
    at Object.dispose (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:236:6172)                                      
    at wd.handleConnectionClosed (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:239:15575)                          
    at wd.handleConnectionClosed (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:243:3421)                           
    at t (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:239:15224)                                                  
    at HT.invoke (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:24:14460)                                           
    at Uu.fire (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:24:15230)                                             
    at Ze (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:25:6505)                                                   
    at HT.invoke (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:24:14460)                                           
    at Uu.fire (/home/diego/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:24:15230)
```

help me please

i try to reinstall jedi, jedi-language-server and coc-jedi

Comment: Use coc's official support channels.